# Extracting Elements from multiple local .html files using GLOB, BS4, and writing to CSV Excel

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, glob

I'm trying to extract the words between a  tag from multiple locally downloaded .HTML files and extract to a CSV. It displays the list of 'titles' when using `print (title)` command but oonce I try to export to an CSV, it only displays one entry.

```
import glob
import lxml
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
path = "C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\lksd\\"
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.html")):
    markup = (infile)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(markup, "r").read(), 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all('title')
    title.append(title)
    print ([title])

with open('output2.csv', 'w') as myfile:
   writer = csv.writer(myfile)
   writer.writerows((title))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You are appending your `title` in the loop to itself:

```
title = soup.find_all('title')
title.append(title)
```

Try to define an empty list outside the loop and append your `title` to this list.

```
...
titleList = []

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.html")):
    markup = (infile)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(markup, "r").read(), 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all('title')
    titleList.append(title)
  
with open('output2.csv', 'w') as myfile:
   writer = csv.writer(myfile)
   writer.writerows((titleList))
```